# C++ Header & Source Files - What To Include And In Which Order

Tags: c++, compilation, include

I just started learning C++ and have trouble understanding the concept of header and source files, specifically which ones I'm supposed to include where.

Suppose I have the classes A and B, each of whose contents are seperated into a header file and a source file, and I have a file in which I want to use those classes.

```
├ A.h
├ A.cpp
├ B.h
├ B.cpp
└ Main.cpp
```

Which file do I need to include where, and is it possible to compile/link all files with a single command?

Comment: `is it possible to compile/link all files with a single command?` compilers usually do that with a single command. What exactly doesn't work for you here?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind I just didn't get to this step yet because I wanted to understand the include directive first. What I meant was: If I understand it correctly, the file order plays a role when compiling. In which order do I have to compile the files for it to work?

Comment: the order of files when doesn't play any role, it just checks that *declaration* of the used functions exist, but not definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which file do I need to include where

`#include` directive in fact is very simple preprocessor directive, which just adds content of the specified file into the target file. Conventionally you keep declaration of functions in a header file and definition of the said functions in the corresponding `cpp` file, and thus you at least want to have the header included there (in your case `A.cpp` includes `A.h` and `B.cpp` includes `B.h`). Additionally you include headers in any file where you use the functions declared in the headers (e.g. if you use declarations of `A.h` and `B.h` in `Main.cpp` you include those files as well).

P.S. You, however, can define everything right in the header file, next to declarations, but as I said earlier preprocessor doesn't do anything fancy - it just adds the content of the include in the target file, and you usually don't want to have all definitions in place, because each translation unit which has it included will have the same definitions repeated over and over again.

Comment: If the functions are only declared but not defined in the header files, then how can I use them in `Main.cpp` when I only included the headers?

Comment: @RalphBear this is why linking happens. Compilers generate object files out of each `.cpp` file, and (at least) one of those object files should contain the definition. Linker then for each function used elsewhere, finds the corresponding definition in the corresponding object file

Answer (score 1):

You include what you need.

If `A.cpp` needs `A.h` then it should include it. Same for `B.cpp` probably needing to include `B.h`.

If `Main.cpp` uses `A` and `B` then it should include `A.h` and `B.h`.

`Main.cpp` should not rely on indirect includes. For example of `A.h` does include `B.h` then `Main.cpp` using both `A` and `B` should still include `A.h` and `B.h` even if the code would compile if `Main.cpp` would only directly include `A.h` (and by that also indirectly including `B.h`.)

In Which order?

If you follow the rule of always including what you use (rather than relying on indirectly including a header or rely on some other header being included before) then the order of `#include` directives should not matter. Changing order of includes breaking a build hints on a problem with includes in one of the headers that should be fixed. If you do things right then order of includes is just a matter of style.